# Experiencing trouble with Picker in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

Running into an issue using a Picker against an enum. Trying to create a workout app, where each Day (type, 7) of the ExercisePlan needs assigned to a DayType (enum). Then I'd build out the ability to add Workouts (type).

I'm currently just going the lazy route and defining an array of Days in the view. The issue comes when I use a Picker. I can successfully make one change, but then immediately all of the Pickers stop working.

Day

```
struct Day: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    var id: Int // 1 - 7
    var type: DayType
    var workout: [Workout]?
    
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.type = .rest
        self.workout = [Workout]()
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: Day, rhs: Day) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case type
        case workout
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        type = try values.decode(DayType.self, forKey: .type)
        
        if values.contains(.workout) {
            workout = try values.decode([Workout]?.self, forKey: .workout)
        } else {
            workout = nil
        }
    }
}
```

DayType

```
enum DayType: Hashable, Codable, CaseIterable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    case upper
    case lower
    case core
    case lowerAndCore
    case rest
    
    var id: Self { self }
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .upper:
            return "Upper"
        case .lower:
            return "Lower"
        case .core:
            return "Core"
        case .lowerAndCore:
            return "Lower and Core"
        case .rest:
            return "Rest"
        }
    }
}
```

ViewCode, including Picker

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExercisePlanBuilderView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MainViewModel
    @State var selectedUser: User
    @State var days = [Day(id: 1), Day(id: 2), Day(id: 3), Day(id: 4), Day(id: 5), Day(id: 6), Day(id: 7)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        model.showExerciseBuilder = false
                    }
                }, label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                            .foregroundStyle(.red)
                        
                        Text("Discard")
                            .foregroundStyle(.red)
                            .bold()
                    }
                })
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text("Exercise Plan Builder")
                    .bold()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            ScrollView {
                ForEach($days, id: \.id) { day in
                    HStack {
                        Text("Day " + day.id.description + " - ")
                            .font(.title)
                        
                        Picker("Select a day focus", selection: day.type) {
                            ForEach(DayType.allCases, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0.description).tag($0)
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(.segmented)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ExercisePlanBuilderView(model: MainViewModel(), selectedUser: User())
}
```

Clicking them still shows a list to choose from, but anything beyond that first selection doesn't take affect. I've tried a few different ways to write this with no luck.

Comment: The tag type should match the selection type. A string isn’t a day type

Comment: Thank you. I had attempted this. It still only allows me to change one of the 7 pickers, and only one time, then the Pickers all stop responding while the rest of the UI remains responsive. I'll edit the post to reflect this change.

Comment: Unless you have an exceptional reason never override Equatable and Hashable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Equatable` and `Hashable` implementations only compares `id`:

```
static func ==(lhs: Day, rhs: Day) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}
```

This means that after selecting a different `DayType` with the picker, *nothing* changes, as far as SwiftUI can see. The `@State` of `days` is still equal to what it originally was. That causes SwiftUI to not update anything in the UI.

You should also take `type` into account:

```
static func ==(lhs: Day, rhs: Day) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.type == rhs.type
}

func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
    hasher.combine(type)
}
```

Or use the automatically generated implementations if possible.

Note that equality and identity are different concepts. It's the difference between "something changed about this `Day`" and "this `Day` has magically disappeared and a new `Day` appears".

`Identifiable` is already satisfied by the `id` property, which I recommend declaring as a `let` instead of a `var`. You don't need the `id:` parameter for `ForEach` - just do `ForEach($days) { day in ...`

You shouldn't make the equality of your struct based solely on its identity. Properties of a `Day` can change (equality), without changing what `Day` it is (identity).

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach using `struct Day: Identifiable, Codable {..}` without the `Hashable` and `Equatable` code (use the defaults for those).

Also using `ForEach($days) { $day in ...`

and

`Picker("Select a day focus", selection: $day.type) {...`

as shown in the example code.

```
struct Day: Identifiable, Codable {  // <--- here
    var id: Int // 1 - 7
    var type: DayType
    var workout: [Workout]?
    
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.type = .rest
        self.workout = [Workout]()
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, type, workout
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        type = try values.decode(DayType.self, forKey: .type)
        
        if values.contains(.workout) {
            workout = try values.decode([Workout]?.self, forKey: .workout)
        } else {
            workout = nil
        }
    }
}

struct ExercisePlanBuilderView: View {
    // ...
    @State var days = [Day(id: 1), Day(id: 2), Day(id: 3), Day(id: 4), Day(id: 5), Day(id: 6), Day(id: 7)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // ...
            ScrollView {
                ForEach($days) { $day in  // <--- here
                    HStack {
                        Text("Day " + day.id.description + " - ").font(.title)
                        
                        Picker("Select a day focus", selection: $day.type) {  // <--- here
                            ForEach(DayType.allCases, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0.description).tag($0)
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}